# Javascript deleting a property from an array of objects with a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, nested

I have an array of objects:

```
const car = [{
  color: 'blue',
  brand: 'Ford'
},{
  color: 'red',
  brand: 'Chevy'
}]
```

I'm trying to create a function that will remove a given property.  For example, I want to remove the 'color' property from all car objects.  If I write the following code it works:

```
car.forEach(function(v){ delete v.color})
```

However, if I try to create a function to do this, it doesnt work:

```
function removeP(arr, keyPar) {
  arr.forEach(function(v){ delete v.keyPar});
}

removeP(car, color)
```

I've also tried calling the function as:

```
removeP(car,'color')
```

which, at least doesnt give me an error, but also doesnt work.

Why isnt this function working?

Comment: Use bracket notation instead

Comment: @BradyB if you need to get only certain property from array of object, you can use `map`  Like this : `car.map(({brand})=>({brand}))`

Answer (score 0):

You should use bracket notation when storing keys in variables:

```js
const car = [{
  color: 'blue',
  brand: 'Ford'
},{
  color: 'red',
  brand: 'Chevy'
}];

function removeP(arr, keyPar) {
  arr.forEach(function(v){ delete v[keyPar]});
}

removeP(car, 'color');

console.log(car);
```

Comment: That did it.  I appreciate the response.  I obviously need more practice.  Thanks!